# Multiple dynamic filter for Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vuetify.js, geojson

I would like to make a dynamic filter of the array of the points on the map with many filters working simultaneously. Data is taken from geoJson.

I have 5 parameters, which filter the dots on a Leaflet map. Each point of a map has a parameter: power, operator name, and 3 others.

These parameters are controlled by the Vuetify UI elements: 3 sliders and 2 select elements.

For easiness let's say I have only 2 parameters: power (slider) and operator (select).

For the beginning the list of operators and values of power are pre-defined:

```
 powerLabels: [100, 200, 300, 400],
 operators: ["A", "B", "C"]
```

When filter by power is enabled, I iterate over the array of points satisfied to the filter and

1. add all of them to the map
2. add unique values of the operators to the array of the labels of the select element:

This is the filter for map:

```
filter: 
layer = L.geoJson(myJson, {
        filter: function (feature) {
          if (
            (feature.properties.connector_power >= valPower &&
              feature.properties.location_operator == sOperator) {
            return feature;
          }
```

This is the filter for labels:

```
this.operators.length = 0; // first erase array

        onEachFeature: (feature, lyr) => {
            if (
              this.operators.indexOf(feature.properties.location_operator) === -1 //check if the value is already in the array of labels
            ) {
              this.operators.push(feature.properties.location_operator); //adding unique value to the array
              this.operators.sort();
            }
```

With this, when I'm filtering objects by power value (e.g. >200) I am able to see only a list of the operators, points of which have the power according to the filter (that is good).

But this does not work visa-versa. When I'm choosing the operator, it iterates the points and shows me on a map only the dots related to this operator and since **only they are iterated and the list is recreated** I cannot choose another operator in the select element, satisfied for this power condition, only the chosen one.

One of the possible solutions was - to run a recreation of the list of operators labels only when the power is changing. But in this case, if I first select operator and then power, it still shows only one operator, chosen one (because it iterates the list with only chosen operator).

Comment: You have to keep a copy of all data separately, which gives you all possible filter values, for each criteria. If that's too expensive, extract all possible values of all operators and keep them in a config and read them from there (basically hard-code them). If you have different sets of values for various clients, you'll need to specify the values in some config files, catered to each client). From what you describe, you don't have a coding problem, you have a business logic problem. Nobody can (and nobody should) help you with that. Except the client, of course.